# Combine list A value 0 to list B value 0: Python

Tags: python-2.7

Hi I have 2 list from a from a loop.

A = [basket,fridge,table,basket,fridge] 
B = [banana, apple, grapes, apple, banana]

Is there a way for me to format it as:

c = [basket:banana, fridge:apple, table:grapes, basket:apple, fridge:banana]

or 
c = [basket, banana, fridge, apple, table, grapes, basket, apple, fridge, banana]

My goal would be to list how many bananas in basket; bananas in fridge and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`zip` in Python can give you result you want:

e.g. `c = zip(a, b)`, `c` will contain `[(basket,banana), (fridge,apple), (table,grapes), (basket,apple), (fridge,banana)]`